# Vowel Recognition(substring): Writing an efficient code for larger input

Tags: python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
for z in range(0,n):
    s1=input().lower()
    lst=[]
    for i in range(0,len(s1)):
        for j in range(0,len(s1)+1):
            if s1[i:j]!="":
                lst.append(s1[i:j])
    s2="".join(lst)
    lst2=[item for item in s2]
    k=0
    for item2 in lst2:
        if item2=="a" or item2=="e" or item2=="i" or item2=="o" or item2=="u":
            k=k+1         
    print(k)
```

I want to know from big players that how do you make the existing code more time-efficient for larger inputs. And the time complexity for this is n^2?

Answer (score 0):

If i understood correctly, you need to get the count of vowels in the word or text:

```
string=raw_input("Enter string:")
vowels=0
for i in string:
      if(i=='a' or i=='e' or i=='i' or i=='o' or i=='u' or i=='A' or i=='E' or i=='I' or i=='O' or i=='U'):
            vowels=vowels+1
print("Number of vowels are:")
print(vowels)
```